# How to change a Vue.js data value within a method called by a DOM event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vue.js

Disclaimer: I know that there is data biding in Vue.js.

So I have this:

```
<html>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <input @input="update">
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        new Vue({

            el: '#app',

            data: {

                info: '',

            },

            methods: {

                update: function (event) {

                    value = event.target.value;

                    this.info = value;
                    console.log(value);

                }

            }

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

An input that will trigger a method called `update` every time the user type in something. The idea here is to change the value of the data property called `info` with the value typed in the input by the user.

But, for some reason, the value of the data attribute doesn't change. The current input value is printed normally in the console with the `console.log(value)` call every time the `update` method is fired, but nothing changes to the `info` attribute.

So, how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that i've mixed two different contexts.

In another script I was doing the same thing, but the input was binded to another js cript that was applying a mask to it. So, that caused the problem of the `info` value not being changed.

Then I tried to replicate the problem in this script in the question (without the js mask script) and then I thought that nothing was changing in the `info` attribute because the **chrome extension for Vue.js showed me that the value didn't changed**, was always staying empty no matter how much i've typed in the input (so maybe an environment problem).

In the end this was just a hicup from my part and the real problem lies in binding two different libraries in a single input. Eventually one of them will not work and this is content for another question.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not seeing what your problem is; your example works perfectly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    info: '',
  },
  methods: {
    update: function(event) {
      value = event.target.value;
      this.info = value;
      console.log(value)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input @input="update">
  {{ info }}
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `{{ info }}` and see its value through chrome extension for Vue. You'll see that it won't work. I did the same thing that you did and noticed that the value only get updated when another event from the Vue instance is fired (for some reason).

Comment: If you console.log(this.info) that value is getting changed. I guess I don't understand the problem you are having.

Comment: @MahmudAdam Sorry for not being clear enough. I found the problem and you can check out my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a two-way data binding using `v-model`, thus essentially binding the value of the input field to the `info` property. This way, the value of `info` gets updated as the user enters something in the input field.

Example below:-

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Vue.js stuff</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div id="app">
            <div>You typed {{info}}</div>
            <br>
            <input type="text" v-model="info">
        </div>
    
    </body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                info: ""
            }
        });
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my problem was other thing actually. You can checout my answer here.